# Running a meteor server from terminal

Tags: meteor

What is the default way of running a meteor server ? I used the command

```
meteor run
```

and

```
meteor
```

inside my meteor application folder, and I always get the same output (as long as I have not introduced any bugs) :

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Also is there a way to speed this up ?

As of this post, I am running `Meteor 1.3.2.4`.

**Edit**

Here are two references which use the two different commands

- [Your First Meteor Application: A Complete Beginner's Guide to the
  Meteor JavaScript Framework](http://meteortips.com/)
- [Discover Meteor - Building Realtime JavaScript Web Apps](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meteor` and `meteor run` are equivalent and are the standard way to run the Meteor server via the command line utility during development.

```
Usage: meteor [--release ] [--help]  [args]
       meteor help 
       meteor [--version] [--arch]

With no arguments, 'meteor' runs the project in the current
directory in local development mode. You can run it from the root
directory of the project or from any subdirectory.

Use 'meteor create ' to create a new Meteor project.
Commands:
   run                [default] Run this project in local development mode.
...
```

`run` is the default in case no other command is specified after `meteor`.

The initial run can be a rather slow, and sometimes takes longer than desired to pick up changes.

There is an unofficial [webpack build package](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/) that could be faster in some cases, but there are some things to consider before using it (I would say that it has a slightly higher learning curve than the standard build system, and the file structure and features are slightly different between vanilla meteor and the webpack version).

In the (not-so-distant) future, there are plans to move to the LTS version of Node.js and migrate the build tool to npm, so things are likely to change.